# Create a 2D list that appends value as a column when repeating assign the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list label

```
Label=np.empty((2,1), dtype=object) # array([[None], [None]], dtype=object)
#first row should be like this;
Label[0][0] = [Label[0][0], 1] # output array([[list([1])], [None]], dtype=object)
Label[0][0] = [Label[0][0], 3] # output array([[list([1,3])], [None]], dtype=object)

#the second row
Label[1][0] = [Label[1][0], 2] # output array([[list([1,3])], [list([2])]], dtype=object)
Label[1][0] = [Label[1][0], 4] # output array([[list([1,3])],[list([2,4])]], dtype=object)
```

I have tried the following approaches.

```
#1. 
Label[0][0] = [a + b for (a, b) in zip([Label[0][0]], [1])]
#I got an error -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'


#2.
Label[0][0] = [Label[0][0],1] #It gives a list with a different structure
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this function which helped me for the time being

```
import numpy as np
def add(lst,col):
  if lst == [None] or not last:
      return [col]
  elif len(lst) == 1:
      return [lst[0],col]
  else:        
      n = len(lst)-1
      return np.insert(lst, n, col)
```

This is how I tested it

```
Label=np.empty((2,1), dtype=object)
Label[0][0] = list(add(Label[0][0],1)) #[array([[list([1])],[None]],dtype=object)
Label[0][0] = list(add(Label[0][0],2)) #[array([[list([1,2])],[None]],dtype=object)
Label[0][0] = list(add(Label[0][0],3)) #[array([[list([1,2,3])],[None]],dtype=object)

Label[1][0] = list(add(Label[1][0],4)) #[array([[list([1,2,3])],[list([4])]],dtype=object)
Label[1][0] = list(add(Label[1][0],5)) #[array([[list([1,2,3])],[list([4,5])]],dtype=object)
```